# Tensorflow - Is there a simple way to zero out the losses of the samples with the highest losses in a mini-batch?

Tags: tensorflow

I am training a neural network for classification. In the context of my research, I would like to zero out the (k) highest losses in each minibatch. I couldn't figure out a simple way to perform this procedure, without relying on numpy at some level.

I have tried the following procedure :
1. Compute the argmax indices of the losses array -- It returns a tf Tensor
2. Slice the losses tensor with the indices array

The issue is that the slicing couldn't be performed using a tf Tensor.

```py
# losses is tf.Tensor
ind_sorted = tf.argsort(losses)
losses_sorted = losses[ind_sorted] # Error mentioned above
# The issue is that ind_1_sorted depends on the output of the neural network. I couldn't find an equivalent of the detach method in pytorch

k_smallest_losses = losses_sorted[:k] # Keeping only the k smallest losses
loss = tf.sum(k_smallest_losses) # Performing the summation of the k smallest losses
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to use `tf.nn.top_k`, which returns you both the values and indices of top_k items. (Note to get smallest losses, I add a negative to your loss and convert them back when done).

```py
batch = 2
max_len = 6
losses = tf.random.uniform(shape=[batch, max_len], minval=0, maxval=2, dtype = tf.float32)
bottom_losses_values, bottom_losses_indices = tf.nn.top_k(-losses, k=3)
total = tf.reduce_sum(-bottom_losses_values, axis=-1)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  losses, bottom_losses_values, bottom_losses_indices, total = sess.run([losses, bottom_losses_values, bottom_losses_indices, total])
  print 'original losses\n', losses
  print 'bottom 3 loss values\n', -bottom_losses_values
  print 'bottom 3 loss indices\n', bottom_losses_indices
  print 'total\n', total
```

Results:

```
original losses
[[ 1.45301318  1.65069246  1.31003475  1.71488905  1.71400714  0.0543921 ]
 [ 0.09954047  0.12081003  0.24793792  1.51561213  1.73758292  1.43859148]]
bottom 3 loss values
[[ 0.0543921   1.31003475  1.45301318]
 [ 0.09954047  0.12081003  0.24793792]]
bottom 3 loss indices
[[5 2 0]
 [0 1 2]]
total
[ 2.81744003  0.46828842]
```